# Como executar instrução ROL no Assembly inline?

Tags: c, assembly

Galera, to com um problema pra executar a instrução de rolar para a esquerda em Assembly num código em C. 
Todos os sites que eu pesquiso mostram dessa forma, mas o compilador diz que há muitas referências de memória para "ROL". 
Já tentei executar outras instruções como MOV e ADD e funcionaram, só essa que eu não consigo. Alguém pode ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int rolar(int a){
    __asm__("rol a, 1");
}
int main(void){
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", rolar(a));
    return 0;
}
```